# How to exclude a folder from a string search

Tags: batch, user-folders, exclude, findstr

```
>>"results\txtmail.txt" findstr /i /p /s mail %userprofile%\*.txt
```

Now, what if I want to exclude C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5 from the search?

Comment: The easiest way might be to hide the folder temporarily while you are doing the search.

Comment: Well that folder is hidden, but it seems that it's getting taken anyway. I can't find the folder by going to the directory, only the batch file can read it.

Comment: You can't easily. You probably need to walk the directory tree using `for /r` and explicitly check for that directory before running `findstr`. See my so documentation [Recursively Visit Directories in a Directory Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3695/for-loops-in-batch-files/12871/recursively-visit-directories-in-a-directory-tree#t=201610032137216676136)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding that `findstr` ignores the hidden bit and finds files in hidden folders regardless, I then used the `for` command (which does respect it) to come up with the following, set out for a batch file:-

```
@echo off
pushd %userprofile%
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do echo %%f | findstr "\Temporary" >NUL: || findstr /i /p mail "%%f" nul:
popd
```

Notes:-

- I've not managed to get `for /r` to work when I add a directory path inside the file match, hence the use of `pushd`/`popd`.
- The first `findstr` looks for `\Temporary` (this could be elaborated) in the file path and executes the second `findstr` only if it's not found.
- The extra `nul:` parameter on the second `findstr` ensures that the file name is printed with the found string: it's normally omitted when there is only one file passed (there may be another way to do this, but I don't often use this command).
- If you are doing this often you may like to consider moving the internet cache to another directory outside the user profile.

I was checking out this solution when David Postill's comment appeared above. I've only just noticed it, but I'll submit my answer anyway, as it adds a couple of points that need to be considered in any solution.

Comment: I tried to run your code and the Content.IE5 folder still appeared, as can be seen in this picture: https://s11.postimg.org/a5xadelmr/Pic_256.png

Comment: I can't test your case directly, as on Win10 the internet cache is organised differently, but I tested on a directory I created with a text file in it, and it worked as expected. However, further investigation shows that text files in the hidden are excluded, but unhidden subdirectories _are_ searched, which seems totally irrational. I have therefore changed my answer to one which works, regardless of the hidden status.